# Notification observers are not working in closures in swift

Tags: ios, swift, closures, nsnotificationcenter

NotificationCenter.default.post is not working in closures

I am having a class with the notification observers

```
     NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.methodOfReceivedNotification(notification:)), name: Notification.Name("Start"), object: nil)

     NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.methodOfReceivedNotification(notification:)), name: Notification.Name("Stop"), object: nil)

     NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.methodOfReceivedNotification(notification:)), name: Notification.Name("Interrupt"), object: nil)
```

In the same class having a method to handle the notification

```
@objc func methodOfReceivedNotification(notification: Notification) {
    print("Notification Received")
}
```

When I am trying to post the observer from another class with the below code it is working fine

```
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("Start"), object: nil)
```

But when trying to post the same thing inside the closure response of the network method it is not calling the methodOfReceivedNotification

Closure code

```
       executeHttpReq(url: getUIUrl(), getparametersDict: getParameters, onSuccess: { (response, status,isEod) -> (
        Any, String,Bool) in

    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("Start"), object: nil)
        return (response,status,isEod)
    }, onFailure: { (error) in
        //todo send stop event to the caller

        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("Stop"), object: nil)

    })
```

Is there any wrong in the code please suggest.

Comment: Does it work without using closure?

Comment: What is your target? In some Apps like Custom Keyboard Extension Notifications don't work. In iOS default app i use your approach and notifications works as we want.

Comment: @AhmadF it  works without closure I need to send observer in closures

Comment: @Agisight I want to send callback response of either start or stop in closures

Comment: Hm... I tried with simple closures and it worked very well. Maybe there is something wrong with your `executeHttpReq`. Are you sure that `executeHttpReq` triggers its callbacks?

Comment: @Agisight even if I put the statement before the executeHttpReq block as well it is not working

Comment: Remember Notification poster and observer both should be on same queue { main }

Answer (score 5):

Try posting the notification in Main queue when it is inside closure.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
   NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("Start"), object: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Create extension

```
extension Notification.Name {
    static let Start = Notification.Name("Start")
    static let Stop = Notification.Name("Stop")
}
```

2. Add following code in `viewDidLoad`

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(onDidReceiveData(_:)), name: .Start, object: nil)
```

3. Add function in your `viewController`

```
 @objc func onDidReceiveData(_ notification:Notification) {
        print("image deleted by user")
       // self.isExcluded = true
   }
```

4. Fire notification in main queue

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
   NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .Start, object: nil)
}
```

Tried with my existing code.

```
RequestManager.shared.doPost(strURL:url, parameter: params) { (response, error) in
            guard error == nil else {
                return
            }
            do {
                if let isSucess = response!["IsSuccessStatusCode"] as? Bool{

                    if isSucess == true{

                                DispatchQueue.main.async {


                                    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .Start, object: nil)

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        self.showValidationAlert(message: "Try after some time")
                    }
                }
                else{
                    self.showValidationAlert(message: "Try after some time")
                }
            }

        }
    }
```